# WPF LIstView Binding to Column Headers

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I'm attempting to create a listview that binds dynamically to a set of dates. So the user would b able to select a date range and the results for the chosen dates would show up with the date in the column header. I've got it all working with just one problem, the dates don't show up in the header. I've got the following which I can't see any reason why it doesn't work:

```
public class KPIResult : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(KPIResult), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResultProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Result", typeof(int), typeof(KPIResult), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public int Result
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ResultProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResultProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And the code for the ListView:

```
    <ListView Margin="6" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=KPICollection}" Name="lvKPIView" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="40" >
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="KPIResult[0]" Content="{Binding Path=KPIResults[0].Date}" />
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=KPIResults[0].Result}" />
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=KPIResults[0].Result}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The results are displayed just fine. Just no dates in headers :(.

Any ideas guys?

Cheers,
SumGuy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<ListView Margin="6" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=This}" ItemsSource="{Binding KPICollection}" Name="lvKPIView" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="40" >
                <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="KPIResult[0]" Content="{Binding KPICollection.KPIResults[0].Date}" />
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=KPIResults[0].Result}" />
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=KPIResults[0].Result}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Apparently, the problem is that you are trying to bind to a property without specifying binding source and without having `DataContext` of the control set to anything. The reason why binding inside `CellTemplate` work is that the data context for rows is automatically set to the corresponding list item instance, but this is not true for headers - they inherit data context from the parent control. So, if we specify `DataContext` for the `ListView` then binding that is used in the header will be have a relative path to that data context: `{Binding KPICollection.KPIResults[0].Date}`