# how to make ListView nonselectable, width like "*", and use DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I am learning to use `ListView` to list data with multiple columns (i.e. column 1 is filename, column 2 is number of pages, etc.), and encountered several problems:

1. The code below shows 2 columns, where the column width is specified by `<GridViewColumn Width="Auto">`. How can I specify the columns to use all available width? I tried to set `Width="*"` like the one for `Grid`, but that generates an error.
2. How to make `ListView` nonselectable? I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398559/there-is-no-listbox-selectionmode-none-is-there-another-way-to-disable-select/8894199#8894199) on making `ListBox` nonselectable, but a similar approach doesn't work for `ListView` (shown in code).

*UPDATE*: solved question #2. see code.

3. Can you show a simple example of a `ListView` using `DataTemplate`? I just want to have something like `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding }" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>` in the MainWindow, so things stay clean.

(4.ish. i learned the code below from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003417/wpf-listview-binding-to-column-headers/5003674#5003674). Please let me know if there is a simpler way.)

Thank you!

```
<ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding }">

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>   <--- disable selection
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Filename"/>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Filename}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Pages"/>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Pages}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
<ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is any other straight-forward solution (although I'm almost sure there is not any direct way to go). The following solution can be considered as a *work-around* but it's actually a beautiful one.

You can make the second column (or generally the last column) fill the remaining space by using some `Binding` to bind the ListView's Columns' Width to the `Grid`'s Columns' Width. Yes we know that only `Grid` has some features which no other controls have. Here are the detailed steps:

- Firstly, we need a `Grid` having the same number of columns with the ListView. The ListView of course should be placed inside this `Grid`. By using `Grid.ColumnSpan` we can make the ListView fill the whole Grid.
- Secondly, bind the Width of all the Grid columns to the ActualWidth of the corresponding ListView columns ***except*** the last Column. The last column of the Grid should have `Width` set to `*` (fill the remaining space).
- Lastly, you need some dummy element (such as a Border) put in the last column of the Grid. We need this dummy element to get its `ActualWidth`, so that we can bind the last ListView column's Width to that `ActualWidth`. A `ColumnDefinition` of the Grid also has the property `ActualWidth` ***but*** it is not a dependency property ***and*** also it does not have any property changed notifying mechanism (so we cannot use that property).

Now is the working code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=firstCol}"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <!-- the dummy element -->
  <Border Grid.Column="1" Name="dummy" Margin="5"></Border>
  <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding }">

     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
          <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
     </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

     <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" x:Name="firstCol">
              <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Filename"/>
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Filename}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>

           <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dummy}">
              <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Pages"/>
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Pages}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>

        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
  <ListView>
</Grid>
```

Note that your original `ListView` may be placed in some Grid (you set its `Grid.Row="0"`). However when using this trick, the `ListView` should always be placed inside a wrapper Grid **and** you have to set `Grid.Row="0"` (although this is set by default) for this wrapper `Grid` instead. I mean this wrapper Grid will be placed in your original `Grid` (if any present).

**Update**: To make it dynamic like as a `Grid`, you need more dummy elements (we use just 1 dummy Border for the last column in the code above). Each dummy elements will be put in each Grid's column. As I explained, we need this to proxy the ActualWidth of the Grid's column, although `ColumnDefinition` also has an `ActualWidth` property but it cannot be used in Binding (does not support any change notification). Here is the code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <!-- the dummy elements -->
  <Border Grid.Column="0" Name="dummy1" Margin="5"></Border>
  <Border Grid.Column="1" Name="dummy2" Margin="5"></Border>
  <!-- your ListView -->
  <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding }">

     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
          <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
     </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

     <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dummy1}">
              <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Filename"/>
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Filename}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>

           <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dummy2}">
              <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Pages"/>
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Pages}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>

        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
  <ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! this solutions gives the all remaining width to the last column; is it possible to assign width based on a predefined ratio? like "2*" and "*"?

Comment: @green the idea is the same, we just need tweak it a little, see my update for details.

Comment: beautiful indeed! now, how can i vote more than once? ;)

Comment: @green accepting the answer is almost enough to me :)